# Injective modules over Fourier algebra

Tags: harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, homological-algebra

Is there any article on injective modules over Fourier Algebras?
Do we have anything about injectivity of $A(G)$ as a $A(G)$-bimodule?

Comment: This is essentially the same as http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99345/homological-properties-of-modules-over-fourier-algebras Let me repeat my comment from that version of the question: *Not to my knowledge. (You probably want to be working in the cb-category, of course.)*

Comment: I should also add that I am reasonably in touch with these matters, and have looked on MathSciNet, so while it is possible that someone has written a paper on this that I don't know of, I must immodestly say that it is unlikely.

Comment: A third comment: it is very unusual for a Banach algebra to be injective over itself as a bimodule, and it is hard to think of applications of this property should it occur. In contrast, asking whether a Banach algebra is *flat* (or projective) over itself as a bimodule seems a much more natural question, at least to me.

Comment: But for example we know that $L^1(G)$ is injective as a left $L^1(G)$-module if and only if $G$ be discrete and amenable.
So this question came to my mind that what append for $A(G)$.

Comment: Zora, I strongly recommend that you either close this question, or close the one of which it is a near duplicate. There is no point having both open.

Comment: One **easy** (bordering on **trivial**) observation: if $G$ is compact then $A(G)$ is operator amenable, so all dual os-bimodules over it are os-injective (and all one-sided os-modules are os-injective), and since $A(G)=B(G)=C^*(G)^*$ in this case we see that $A(G)$ is indeed os-(bi-)injective over itself.

Comment: [deleted earlier comment; I was too hasty, and should think a bit more]

Comment: Is it if and only if? Or just we can say that if G is compact then A(G) is injective as an $A(G)$-bimodule.

Would you please explain "dual os-bimodules over it are os-injective (and all one-sided os-modules are os-injective)" more or suggest me a reference? 

I believe that it is not useless to investigate the injectivity of modules over $A(G)$ since biinjectivity is related to biflatness.

Anyway sometimes I ask silly questions. But at the moment I guess that it is not that silly.  

Comment: Zora, MO is not meant as a tool to help people work their way towards questions. I have no idea if this is "if and only if", because the full homological theory of the Fourier algebra is **hard**, and has not been studied much. Your question is not silly, but MO is not the place for throwing out vague questions and discussing what sticks to the wall and what does not.

Comment: That said: as for a reference, my advice would be to go and read a significant chunk of Helemskii's book, i.e. *learn some homology of Banach algebras* **before** asking questions about the homological properties of the Fourier algebra. Then read the papers of Wood, Spronk et al on adapting some of these notions to the cb-category.

Comment: I should clarify: asking which A(G)-bimodules are bi-injective is a *interesting* (though ambitious) question, at least from the point of view of research. I just think that asking when A(G) itself is bi-injective is somewhat artificial, for the reasons in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: I closed the older version as a duplicate - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99345/homological-properties-of-modules-over-fourier-algebras - the closing votes on this one will clear in a few days...